# How can I change all instances of a string within an HTML document via JS without disturbing its markup?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

I want to write a script that will cause a page to "decay", changing characters at random. Let's say I've got some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="eebee">
    Lorem Ipsum <a href="http://example.com">Anchor here</a>
</div>
```

And I want to replace every instance of "e" with "∑" so it'll be

```
<div class="eebee">
    Lor∑m Ipsum <a href="http://example.com">Anchor h∑r∑</a>
</div>
```

but, obviously, I don't want it to be

```
<div class="∑∑b∑∑">
    Lor∑m Ipsum <a hr∑f="http://∑xample.com">Anchor h∑r∑</a>
</div>
```

How to accomplish this? A DOM parser? Or just some regex, searching for content betw∑∑n ">" and "<"?

EDIT:
As per Oriol's solution below, to put it into a function that accepts any find-and-replace strings:

```
function decay(find_string, replace_string) {
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
    while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        var node = treeWalker.currentNode;
        re = new RegExp(find_string, "g");
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(re, replace_string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple recursive function which iterates all text nodes:

```js
function iterateTextNodes(root, callback) {
  for(var i=0; i<root.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    var child = root.childNodes[i];
    if(child.nodeType === 1) {           // element node
      iterateTextNodes(child, callback); // recursive call
    } else if(child.nodeType === 3) {    // text node
      callback(child);                   // pass it to callback
    }
  }
}
iterateTextNodes(document.body, function(node) {
  node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/e/g, '∑');
});
```

```html
<div class="eebee">Lorem Ipsum <a href="http://example.com">Anchor here</a></div>
```

Or if you prefer a built-in way, you can use a tree walker

```js
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
  var node = treeWalker.currentNode;
  node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/e/g, '∑');
}
```

```html
<div class="eebee">Lorem Ipsum <a href="http://example.com">Anchor here</a></div>
```

Some notes:

- Don't use a HTML parser. If you parse a HTML string and then replace the old DOM tree with the new one, you will remove all the internal data of elements (event listeners, checkedness, ...)
- Especially, never use a regex to parse HTML. [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: Holy crap, that's so easy! And I thought I knew Javascript.